# Plot CDF with GNUPLOT with data not being sorted

Tags: gnuplot

Hi I am trying to write a gnuplot script that produced CDF graph for the data produced from another program.

The data looks like this:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
ABCD11  19.8    1.13    129 2
AABC32  14.3    2.32    109 2
AACd12  19.1    0.21    103 2
```

I want to plot CDF for the column 2. The point is that data in the `col2` might not be sorted.

To compile the script I use online tool such as [here](http://gnuplot.respawned.com/)

The script I tried is:

```
set output 'out.svg'
set terminal svg size 600,300 enhanced fname 'arial' fsize 10 mousing butt solid
set xlabel "X"
set ylabel "CDF"
set style line 2 lc rgb 'black' lt 1 lw 1
set xtics format "" nomirror rotate by -10 font ", 7"
set ytics nomirror

set grid ytics
set key box height .4 width -1 box right
set nokey
set title "CDF of X"

a=0
#gnuplot 4.4+ functions are now defined as:  
#func(variable1,variable2...)=(statement1,statement2,...,return value)
cumulative_sum(x)=(a=a+x,a)
plot "data.txt" using 1:(cumulative_sum($2)) with linespoints lt -1
```

Comment: Also, pipes such as "plot "<awk '{i=i+$2; print $1,i}' test.txt" with lines" don't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cumulative` smoothing style to get a CDF from data, see `help smooth cumulative`:

```
plot "test.dat" u 2:(1) smooth cumulative w lp
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried the same but, I need the running cumulative sum.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... what output would you expect for your example data 19.8, 14.3, 19.1 ? `smooth cumulative` gives the CDF: for any value of `y` it returns the number of data points less than `y`,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the (running) cumulative sum of the values from second column using sorted values, then you could slightly extend your approach based on `awk`. To be more specific, the command would be

```
tail -n+2 'test.txt' | sort -k2,2n | awk '{s+=$2; print NR, s}'
```

Here, `tail` strips off the header (skips the first line), `sort` sorts numerically according to the second column, and finally `awk` calculates the cumulative sum as a function of the number of records/items.

Comment: Not sure if the online compiler such as mentioned in the question will support these operations. 
Basically, the question was to find something pure gnuplot based approach.